# How to implement a complex nested header using the Ant Design (antd) library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want to create a nested header using the Ant Design (antd) library, similar to the image below (red circled area):
[image: Table Illustration]
I've attempted to combine the header with the first row of the body table, but it requires extensive customization for elements like sticky header, header background, and more.

```
const columnHeader: TableColumnsType<DataType> = [
  {
    title: "1/1",
    dataIndex: "category",
    key: "category",
    width: 200,
    fixed: "left",
    align: "left",
  },
  {
    title: "project",
    align: "left",
    children: [
      {
        title: "total",
        dataIndex: "total",
        key: "total",
        width: 140,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "project 1",
    align: "left",
    children: [
      {
        title: "total",
        dataIndex: "project1",
        key: "project1",
        width: 140,
      },
      {
        title: "project 2",
        align: "left",
        children: [
          {
            title: "total",
            dataIndex: "project2",
            key: "project2",
            width: 140,
          },
          {
            title: "total",
            dataIndex: "project3",
            key: "project3",
            align: "left",
            width: 140,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: "project 4",
        align: "left",
        children: [
          {
            title: "total",
            dataIndex: "project4",
            key: "project4",
            width: 140,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: "total",
        dataIndex: "project5",
        key: "project5",
        width: 140,
      },
      {
        title: "total",
        dataIndex: "project6",
        key: "project6",
        width: 140,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

This data is for the header, and for the last row of the header, I retrieve it from the first row of the body table.

Comment: Hello! Can you please share what you have tried so far? (It will help us understand how to help better) Looked up the docs and [this example looks similar to what you have](https://ant.design/components/table#components-table-demo-grouping-columns) and can be a good starting point

Comment: I've read the docs and applied it to the header, but I couldn't find a solution to add a row after the nested header. 
I've added the code I've tried.

Comment: From what I can tell, this is hard to do if you want a fixed header. I tried nesting the children in the columns but it created  subdivisions in the columns where it was not expected. (Try arbitrarily nesting 3 levels down with empty columns with only a children prop to see what that looks like)

If fixed header is not a must, one thought is to just style the first row to look like the header.

Disclaimer: Not an Ant Design user/expert - just trying to help :)